# JQuery Shift-Select Issues

Tags: jquery, select

List of items in a listbox populated using jquery.

I click the first item and it's selected.
I shift clicked the 3rd item and now items 1-3 are selected.
Shift clicking the 6th item only selects 3-6th instead of 1st-6th as you would expect.

Any idea how to fix something like this? :)

Turns out it WAS a logic error on my side. Took me awhile to find the code. :P

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? Show some code if possible.

Comment: What code do you want to see exactly? All the jquery is doing is calling return jQuery(query).children('.ui-selected');

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a custom select replacement, this is browser behavior, not jQuery.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE 8.

Comment: Is this a native multi-select you're using? If you're using some sort of a plugin that's reproducing the behavior of a muli-select (assuming that's what it is?), then this is something we can address.  If it's purely a native muli-select, then you're fighting the default browser behavior... not a custom jQuery behavior.  We could probably answer you better if we had some markup/javascript.